# Example of Duck Typing in Java

Tags: java, reflection, interface, typing

I have been reading examples of representations of Duck Typing in Java with reflection. I would like to know if this is correct:

```
public interface Quackable {
    public void quack();
}
```

In main...

```
Object[] vec = {(Here I add some instances)};

for(int i=0; i < vec.length; i++) {
    if(vec[i] instanceof Quackable)
        vec[i].quack();
}
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Correct in what manner? Your code is correct but there's no duck typing here.

Comment: Why not just create the array of type Quackable[] (or a List of type Quackable).

Comment: Well, the idea is to know in execution time if an instance implements the Quackable Interface. If it does, then it can quack. Isn't that duck typing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no duck typing in Java as it is in Python. You can use reflection to find if the class has a method you want to call but it is really a hassle.

It looks like that

```
Class<?> aClass = object.getClass();
try {
    Method method = aClass.getMethod("methodName", argType1, argType2);
    method.invoke(arg1, arg2)
} catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It is also not possible in every environment. If security manager is enabled your code should have sufficient rights to execute the code above. That also adds substantial work.